# Questions related to photons spin

Tags: polarization

Let's assume a photon is moving in the $z$ direction and state of the photon is represented by
$$|\psi\rangle  = \alpha |x\rangle + \beta |y\rangle $$

This photon will pass through three polarizers. One is oriented in the y direction along the horizontal, second is by 45 degree and third one is along the $x$ direction.

I have written the matrix representation of the photon 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos \theta  \\
  \sin \theta  
 \end{pmatrix}$$

And let represent  the state along $x$ and $y$ axis by 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  1   \\
  0  
 \end{pmatrix}  \hspace{0.3cm}\text{and} \hspace{0.3cm}\begin{pmatrix}
  0   \\
  1
 \end{pmatrix}$$.

I understand what's the probability of getting each state ofter entering the each polarizer. My problem is that, i want to write the polarization state as a total Eigen  ket space. Could you please enlighten me how to write the ket space whenever a polarized light enters into a polarizer. You can give me an example. I'm fine with that.

You are welcome to improve the question or ask me so I can add more information to the question.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_polarization for an image of how the spin of the photon builds up the polarization of the classical wave, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need to revisit the [fundamentals](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch3.pdf) of quantum mechanics. A polarizer is effectively a measurement device. For example the horizontal polarizer would correspond to a measurement operator $|y\rangle \langle y|$ in your notation, the vertical one, to $|x\rangle \langle x|$ and the diagonal to $(|x\rangle +|y\rangle )(\langle x|+\langle y|)/2$. The probability to pass a horizontal polarizer would be |$\langle y | \psi \rangle |^2$ and if the photon passes it, its state $becomes$ $| y \rangle$. The same logic applies for the rest of the polarizers.